# Android Studio third dependencies package import intellisense did not work

Tags: flutter

Today I am facing a problem that the third party dependencies package import intellisense did not work. This is a simple code, I am using [get](https://pub.dev/packages/get) in flutter like this:

```
class WordProvider extends GetConnect {

}
```

this is the part of the dependencies define in my project:

```
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^1.0.0
  get: 4.3.8
```

as expect, the android studio should give me tips should import the `package:get/get.dart` after the mouse hang over the `GetConnect`, but it not give any import suggestion. I have tried:

```
File-> Ivalidate caches / Restart -> Invalidate and Restart
```

still did not work. This is my env information:

```
[dolphin@MiWiFi-R4CM-srv]~/Documents/GitHub/reddwarf-dict% flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.5.2, on Fedora 32 (Workstation Edition) 5.11.22-100.fc32.x86_64, locale en_US.UTF-8)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    ✗ Android SDK file not found: /home/dolphin/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-31/android.jar.
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2021.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.60.2)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category
```

why would this happen and what should I do to fix it? This is android studio version info:

```
Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 2
Build #AI-203.7717.56.2031.7678000, built on August 26, 2021
Runtime version: 11.0.10+0-b96-7249189 amd64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
Linux 5.11.22-100.fc32.x86_64
GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 4096M
Cores: 16
Registry: ide.instant.shutdown=false, external.system.auto.import.disabled=true
Non-Bundled Plugins: com.bakerj.flutter.fishreduxtemplate.id, com.bloc.intellij_generator_plugin, com.intellij.marketplace, Dart, com.thoughtworks.gauge, org.jetbrains.kotlin, io.flutter, org.intellij.plugins.markdown
Current Desktop: GNOME
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the dependency and run `flutter clean` and after that run:

```
flutter pub add get
```

Comment: I tried what you said, but it seems did not work as expect. @Amir Hossein Rahmanzadeh

Comment: @Dolphin Are you able to run other projects or the default project of flutter? (The counter app) since you have an issue in your `flutter doctor` log

Comment: I could success run the app. @Amir Hossein Rahmanzadeh

Comment: @Dolphin Set the android sdk path and see if the issue remains the same: `flutter config --android-sdk <path-to-your-android-sdk-path>`